# Windows phone application

Tags: c#, javascript, html, windows-phone-7

Just started to look on how to develop on windows phone and i found about PhoneGap and Visual WebGui and i thought about the next ideea: if i start a new silverlight for windows phone application in visual studio and i create a web browser, like i saw in PhoneGap, and to use javascript and html5 for the application. The problem is that i want to use Sockets from C# (since javascript only has websockets... ), i know i can use java script code in C# to manipulat a html5 page but is it possible if the user clicks a button to use the Socket from C# to send a message to the server(like using javascript to call a method written in C#)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create your own FFI between JS & C# to create a bridge in both directions. The PhoneGap code should provide a good example of how to call in both directions.